# A list of professionally-useful and safe file types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, file-type, whitelist

I have a system where users can upload, well, anything really - and these files are available to other users.

I need to come up with a list of file types that are genuinely needed by **professionals in different industries** that are safe from hacking/viruses, etc.

.doc .docx .gif .jpg .jpeg .mpg .mpeg .mp3 .odt .odp .ods .pdf .ppt .pptx .tif .tiff .txt .xls .xlsx .wav

What other file types do you know of that are both useful and safe?

### Clarification

Many of the comments and responses are asking for a clearer definition of 'safe from hacking/viruses' - I ask the question with precisely that level of detail because I don't have as sophisticated an understanding of file types and their risks as many of you do, and I would like guidance on 1) any file types that may keep my site more secure, and 2) if there *are* no 'safe' file types then any advice on how to move forward with a system that allows for flexible uploading and sharing of files.

If indeed any malicious file can be packaged as a seemingly-safe file, how can I protect my users?

Comment: "safe from hacking/viruses"?  What does that mean?  If you think '.doc' or '.xls' are safe from viruses, you'll need to provide a definition of what you think "safe from viruses" means.

Comment: You can't assume a file is safe until you check the file's contents, in fact .docx, pptx and .xslx are .zip files underneath. Go ahead and rename them .zip and open them up.... Besides, some major Operating System exploits have been achieved through image files (.gif .jpg .jpeg .tif .tiff) and that's not to mention the very unsafe MS Office files (.doc .docx .ppt .pptx .xls .xlsx). Not too long ago one of the exploits the allowed the iPhone to be jailbroken was through a bug on the .tiff rendering system

Comment: just block .virus. That'll do it

Comment: @Juandg - thank you for one of the more useful answers here. Given that nearly any file can apparently be used to stage an attack, what is best practice for vetting attachments in a website? If I cannot use the file type, then what should I use?

Comment: Old office files (.doc, .ppt, .xls) are dangerous, but Microsoft has gone to great lengths to make sure that the new variations are safe. Modern Excel spreadsheets (.xlsx) for instance do not contain macros. The macros are stored in separate (.xlsm) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume that all files with a given extension is safe from 'viruses'.

I can easily rename a malicious executable to `.doc` and 'hack' your system.

EDIT:

There is no (simple?) way to check whether a user-uploaded file is malicious or not.

The app that you're creating is no different than any other file sharing websites out there (Rapidshare, Megaupload, etc).

There is nothing stopping anyone to upload malicious files to those websites.

Comment: @ryanprayogo - Thank you for your answer! I understand that this may be harder than I was anticipating - how then would sites like Rapidshare and Megaupload deal with these malicious files?

Comment: @sscirrus they don't, many a virus is spread through those download sources.

Comment: @Chad, @ryanprayogo - Is there ANY way then to safely allow one website user to share a file with a limited group of other users? Is there literally no safe way to do this, nomatter how restricted?

Comment: @sscirrus You could have a server-side running AV that scans all incoming files.

Comment: I can't think of any method other than what @Chad mentioned, ie, running AV on your server that scans all incoming files.

Comment: @Chad, @ryanpraygogo - hopefully last question on this: how can AV be set up on Heroku?

Comment: @sscirrus that is a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Share the files on a Dropbox (or similar) account. Of course, before using it, you will still have to check wether a file is malicious or not but the risks of malicious files are not on your server anymore.

Answer (score 3):

**No** filetype is safe if the program you use to open it with is badly (or carelessly or evil-y) written.

Answer (score 2):

Safe files does not exists. The ordinary text file is safe? For example with content:

```
format c:
```

if some program can execute a content of the file... you get the idea.

So, here are not safe files - only restrictions to RUN code (programs). (And I understand if this answer does not like.) :)

Answer (score 1):

For "useful" you'll need to ask your customers.

For safe, there's no such thing because a file extension is just a part of the file name that gives a **suggestion** of what type of file it is.  It need not accurately represent the type, and is easily manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than protecting based on file type. I would get a 3rd party to virus scan each file on upload. Reject those which are identified as positive.

Comment: do you know any examples of those 3rd parties who could do this scanning? How would they integrate into Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

The list is pretty endless! A quick search finds [http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=^A](http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=%5EA)

Comment: He's asking for a list of "safe" file extension, not all "possible" file extensions

Comment: @juandg OP is also asking for a a list of file types that are genuinely needed by professionals. Depends what field you're in, could be anything really

Answer (score 0):

Well you can include all *data* files and exlude all executable/script files.
One list of executable file extensions is here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/execfileext.htm

you may look other sources to inprove coverage.

Edit: for second part of the question addressing sequrity-
It would be best to have bunch of anti malware software installed on the server to check each sumbission - they are designed for this specialized task, use them. Anyways no executable file is professionaly useful as long as people are not looking for crackware.

Comment: "Security" done badly is worse than doing nothing, because it gives a false sense of security. Particulary naive is the attempt to protect users from harmful file *content*  by looking at the file *name*. It has yet to happen that a file name did the slightest harm, even if it is ThisIsADangerousVirus.cmd

Comment: Where do you think I talked about security? The question has two parts: File extensions and security. I answered first part only.

Comment: Why then did you give the advice "exclude all executable .. files"?

Comment: And security can be done easily by having tons of anti malware software installed on server which are specialized to this kind of task instead of having some custom fishy logic to *smell* file contents.

Comment: Q: Why then did you give the advice "exclude all executable .. files"? A: For profesionally useful files - i dont think anyone is interested in executables unless they are looking for crackware and data files would seldom be named as ImportantDocument.exe